# How can I convert remote json from angular $http to string?

Tags: javascript

I'm using angular js $http to get remote json, however I'm unable to convert the json objects returned to a string with the stringify method. Is there a special way I have to do it when dealing with angular? I'm new to angular. So I'm a little confused. Here's an example:

```
 $http.jsonp('http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent('http://www.website.com/api-radio/' + num) + '&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
        .success(function (response) {
         result = angular.fromJson(response.contents);
         var JsonToBe = result.shows;
         var JsonVariable = JSON.stringify(JsonToBe); //this won't work.
```

Comment: describe "won't works", any errors in the console?

Comment: Please provide a more useful explanation than "this won't work".

Comment: @FelixKling This won't work means, it won't make that json a string

Comment: @FelixKling I get back nothing and I've checked the JSON itself. It's fine. When using a $.getJSON to retrieve it, it works fine and then I can convert the objects to a string but when working with angular, I can't.

Comment: Is jsonp giving you a string? I think its already an object. So no need for angular.fromJSON.

Comment: Yeah, did you check what `result` is? JSONP has actually not much to do with JSON, on the client side.

Comment: @FelixKling the result, I put in an alert message. I get [object Object] back

Comment: Use `console.log(result)` instead.